# Excel VBA function collapses if variables have declared type

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a short function to calculate a power of a number modulo N. I can get out of the range of any integer like type, so I've written a loop, that calculates only modulus values:

```
Function ModPwr(b As Integer, e As Integer, m As Integer) As Integer
Dim r As Integer
r = 1
Do While e > 0
    r = r * b Mod m
    e = e - 1
Loop
ModPwr = r
End Function
```

The function collapses or return zero for some input (eg: 217, 143, 221). If I completly remove all "As Integer" and the Dim declaration, everything works fine:

```
Function ModPwr(b, e, m)
r = 1
Do While e > 0
    r = r * b Mod m
    e = e - 1
Loop
ModPwr = r
End Function
```

I have to implement an RSA demo in Excel to demonstrate the encryption/decryption method (using small primes!). I am a newby in VBA.

In other (more complicated) functions I need the type declaration, so I have to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, an integer can have a maximum value of 32,767. I'm guessing you're exceeding that and getting an error.

When you don't declare your variable `As Integer`, it is automatically created as type `Variant` which has a much larger maximum value.

Comment: To add a little clarity here, declaring it as type Long will exponentially increase the value able to be held in the variable.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon it will increase it from 181 to 46340.

Answer (score 0):

Your data type needs to be able to handle up to `m * m`.  The Integer datatype has a maximum value of 2^15-1 (or 32,767), so can handle **m** up to 181.

The default data type works because it's `double` which has a large range, but is also not an exact numeric.  Whet you probably want is to declare everything as `Decimal` which has a range up to ***10^28***, so can handle **m** up to 100,000,000,000,000 and is an exact numeric.

Comment: Thanks! It works! I use Long as ULong and Decimal is not recognized by Excel for Mac 2011. For the demonstration of RSA I need just two small primes (eg. 13, 17). Long is enough.